# Consecutive numbering of data.frame segments

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I wanted to assign consecutive numbers to segments of my data.frame. I tried like so:

```
library(plyr)
ex1 <- mtcars
ehh <- ddply(.data=ex1, .variables=c("cyl"), transform, brx_j = c(1:nrow(cyl)))
```

But it's an "Error in data.frame(list(mpg = c(22.8, 24.4, 22.8, 32.4, 30.4, 33.9, 21.5,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 11, 0".

What's my mistake here?

Comment: I think you need `seq_along(cyl)`, if you are using `dplyr`, then  `ex1 %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(brx_j = row_number())`

Comment: Replace `nrow` by `length` - `mtcars$cyl` is a vector, not a matrix

Comment: sweet! You guys are the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `seq_along` instead of `1:nrow` as 'cyl' is a single column and not a `data.frame`.

```
ddply(.data=ex1, .variables=c("cyl"), transform, brx_j = seq_along(cyl))
```

and with `dplyr`, there is `row_number()` function to get the sequence after grouping by 'cyl'.

```
library(dplyr)
ex1 %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     mutate(brx_j = row_number())
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work (base R):

```
ex1$brx_j <- ave(1:nrow(ex1), ex1$cyl, FUN=seq_along)
ex1[order(ex1$cyl),]
```